# Azure functions to get a list of resource groups in a subscription - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have created a function that would get me the list of resource groups within a subscriptions

```
// Function to get the resource group
const getHttp = async (subscriptionId) => {
    const response = await fetch(
        `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?api-version=2019-10-01`
    );

    if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } else {
        throw new Error(
            'Unable to get list of resource group from Azure' +
                ' ' +
                response.status
        );
    }
};

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('ListRG proccessed a request');
    const subscriptionId = 'xxx';

    const json = await getHttp(subscriptionId);

    console.log(json);
    context.log(json);
    context.res = { body: json };
};
```

but I get:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

and this error:

`2020-08-07T11:25:27.915 [Error] Executed 'Functions.ListRg' (Failed, Id=4a10c117-5ded-4bb4-882e-94ec4eb6e28b, Duration=36ms)Result: FailureException: Error: Unable to get list of resource group from AzureStack: Error: Unable to get list of resource group from Azureat getHttp (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ListRg\index.js:12:9)at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)at async module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ListRg\index.js:20:15)`

For permissions, I used managed identities and gave the function Reader role in my subscription

[image]

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, we can't call the rest api directly although we have enabled MSI. If you want to use MSI to request for the resource groups list, please refer to the solution I provided below:

**1.** Install the modules:

```
npm install ms-rest-azure
npm install azure-arm-resource
```

**2.** Please refer to my code below:

```
const msRestAzure = require("ms-rest-azure");
const { ResourceManagementClient } = require("azure-arm-resource");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    credentials = await msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({ resource: 'https://management.azure.com' });

    const subscriptionId = '<your subscription id>';

    const resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);

    let finalResult = await resourceClient.resourceGroups.list();

    finalResult.forEach(element => { 
        console.log(element); 
    });

    context.res = { body: 'success' };

}
```

By the way, my solution uses sdk to do the request. If you want to request the api `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?api-version=2019-10-01` directly in your function code, you need to get the access token first and then set the token in the header of your "Fetch". But in my opinion, I suggest you to use sdk.

Comment: Hey Hury, many thanks ! really helped a lot, a question though.

How did you know ? i really looked around in many  place before asking here and found nonthing

Comment: Hi @Renm I know that we can't request the api directly in azure function although we enable MSI (this is equivalent to a request from any client). So I look for some information and find this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-node-manage-resources-with-msi) which is similar to your problem.